# How to propagate a value in a TinkerPop graph

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

How would I 'propagate' a value through a TinkerPop graph? i.e. given a value of a property on one vertex, I want to 'move' that value along an edge to another vertex, or set of vertices.

Example, given this simple graph of 3 vertices and 2 edges connecting them:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> a = g.addV('name','a','amount', 100).next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> b = g.addV('name','b','amount', 0).next()
==>v[3]
gremlin> c = g.addV('name','c','amount', 0).next()
==>v[6]
gremlin> a.addEdge('drain', b, 'factor', 0.5)
==>e[9][0-drain->3]
gremlin> b.addEdge('drain', c, 'factor', 0.1)
==>e[10][3-drain->6]
gremlin>
```

I wish to run some kind of operation on this graph such that the `amount` in `a` gets copied to `b` multiplied by the `factor` in the edge connecting them. E.g. b['amount'] would equal 50. Then propagated further c['amount'] would equal 5.

Ideally I'd like to know a single statement that could propagate the value all the way down the chain in one go, but also a statement that might propagate it to just the first adjacent vertex then on second invocation would propagate it to the next vertex, etc.

Is this something that can be accomplished simply in Gremlin, or do I need some other part of TinkerPop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this using Gremlin [sacks](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sack-step):

```
gremlin> g.withSack(a.value('amount')).
           V(a).repeat(outE('drain').sack(mult).by('factor').
                       inV().property('amount', sack())).
                until(__.outE('drain').count().is(0)).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[amount:[100],name:[a]]
==>[amount:[50.0],name:[b]]
==>[amount:[5.00],name:[c]]
```

I initialized the "sack value" equal to the "amount" in vertex "a" and begin the traversal there iteratively traversing out on the "drain" edges where we multiply (i.e. `mult`) the value in the sack by the "factor" property on the "drain" edges. The sack then gets assigned to the next vertex via the `property()` step.

Note that you could control the "drain" (i.e. how far down the chain you'd like to go) with the appropriate looping semantics on `repeat`. Right now it uses `until()` "there are no more outgoing edges". But you might also terminate just ones step away as follows:

```
gremlin> g.withSack(a.value('amount')).
           V(a).repeat(outE('drain').sack(mult).by('factor').
                       inV().property('amount', sack())).
                times(1).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[amount:[100],name:[a]]
==>[amount:[50.0],name:[b]]
==>[amount:[0],name:[c]]
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for this! If I wanted to extend the general problem further such that there was logic on each vertex as to whether the values propagated or not and perhaps the value itself might be a function of several properties on the vertex, would writing a VertexProgam to be run on the GraphComputer be the way to go? An do they have to be written in Java, or could they use the python variant?

Comment: Adding those additional features to the above wouldn't be too hard and shouldn't require a VertexProgram. To prevent propogation, you just need to control the loop, so make your `until()` evaluate the vertex properties to determine if it should break. If you need more complex logic for incrementing the sack there are a couple options: First, you can chain calls to `sack()`. Second, you could use a lambda for modifying the sack value. At the end of the day the `sack()` method just takes a `BiFunction` so the calculation could do whatever you want. 'mult' is just a helper operator.

Comment: `VertexProgram` instances must be written in java. They are part of the core API and not extended to GLVs (Gremlin Language Variants).

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. The next problem I'm trying to solve is instead of propagating the value along the chain as above, how I would increment/decrement a property on a vertex by a value in an edge property leading to it. I'll write that up as a separate question though once I've had a few more attempts at it.